# bash script to execute a program sequentially

Tags: bash

I have a problem with a bash script I am trying to use. I have a directory with 1000s of files and I want to run a command sequentially using each file. However, each file is paired with another, e.g File1.sam, File1.gz, File2.sam, File2.gz etc.. and the command I am executing requires that I use both files from a pair as arguments. I have been using something similar to the command below when only a single argument was required, and I thought (wrongly) that I could just simply extend it like below.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for myfile1 in *.sam && for myfile2 in *.gz 
do
./bwa samse -r "@RG\tID:$myfile1\tLB:$myfile1\tSM:$myfile1\tPL:ILLUMINA" lope_V1.2.fasta    $myfile1 $myfile2 > $myfile1.sam2 2>$myfile1.log
done
```

Anyone know how I can modify this or point me in the direction of another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for myfile1 in *.sam
do
  myfile2=$(echo $myfile1|sed s/.sam$/.gz/)
  ./bwa samse -r "@RG\tID:$myfile1\tLB:$myfile1\tSM:$myfile1\tPL:ILLUMINA" lope_V1.2.fasta $myfile1 $myfile2 > $saiFile.sam 2>$saiFile.log
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not generate the second filename, e.g. replace .sam with .gz

```
for myfile1 in *.sam  ; do
  myfile2="${myfile1%.sam}.gz"
  [ -e "$myfile2" ] || continue
  ./bwa samse -r "@RG\tID:$myfile1\tLB:$myfile1\tSM:$myfile1\tPL:ILLUMINA" lope_V1.2.fasta "$myfile1" "$myfile2" > "$saiFile".sam 2>"$saiFile".log
done
```

Comment: Looks good.  Only suggestion for improvement would be using a more strict PE `myfile2="${myfile1%.sam}.gz"`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you had removed the $myfile1 parameter expansions from the quotes on the `./bwa` line.  Why did you do this?  This will break due to wordsplitting if the filenames have whitespace.

Comment: @JoshCartwright i didn't saw the quotes around the line, in general i tend to quote everything but i didn't saw the quotes at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 1):

Iterate only over files with one of the extensions (for instance `*.gz`) and use for instance sed to get the matching `.sam` file.

Something like this:

```
for myfile1 in *.sam 
do
  sam_name=`echo $myfile | sed -e s#gz\\$#sam#`
  ./bwa samse -r "@RG\tID:$myfile1\tLB:$myfile1\tSM:$myfile1\tPL:ILLUMINA" lope_V1.2.fasta       $myfile1 $myfile2 > $saiFile.sam 2>$saiFile.log
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop using one of the file extensions and calculate the other file name.  For example:

```
for p in a b c; do touch $p.1 $p.2; done
for f in *.1; do g=${f%%.}.2; echo $f $g; done
```

This displays:

```
a.1 a.2
b.1 b.2
c.1 c.2
```